# Is there a functional difference between these two stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, atomic

Is there a case where these two versions of a stored procedure are different? Such as producing a conflict/deadlock, or one is not atomic, or the outputs could be off? This procedure is just simply to increment an int and return the value pre-increment. In my view, they both properly lock on the row and return the output in the case of the procedure running multiple times at the same time.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am not looking for an alternate solution. I am just looking for a detailed explanation of the intricacies of the queries and their differences in terms of transaction and atomicity. This is more to learn what to do/what not to do in these scenarios in the future.

```
@LocationCode nvarchar(131),
@VID int OUTPUT
```

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE NextVID WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET NextVID = NextVID + 1, 
    @VID = NextVID
WHERE LocationCode = @LocationCode;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

vs.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT 
    @VID = NextVID
FROM NextVID WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE LocationCode = @LocationCode;

UPDATE NextVID
SET NextVID = NextVID + 1
WHERE LocationCode = @LocationCode;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: The real issue here is that you are rolling your own incremental logic instead of using the ones already built into sql server. Using an identity or a sequence is a MUCH better approach.

Comment: @SeanLange . . . The OP is incrementing the values *per* location.  That is not something natively supported in SQL Serrver.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hence the reason I mentioned a sequence. These roll your own quasi-identity approaches are always problematic because there are so many ways to get it wrong. And it usually comes back to an over reliance on numbers being sequential.

Comment: I can not use a sequence because it is not feasible to manage a sequence per location.

Comment: Then I would say you should check the documentation as this is explained in great detail. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I understand both queries listed above individually. From the documentation you linked, both queries would stand to be exactly the same. I am wondering if they are in fact exactly the same or they behave slightly differently in ms-sql engine.

Comment: Well there are different locks in those queries. I am not sure if you are asking how the query engine works or if logically these are the same from a functional standpoint. I assume the latter, and AFAIK they should behave almost identically.

Comment: I am asking if the engine interprets these two queries exactly the same, and there are no possible differences such as if 1000 of the same queries were running at the "same time", the results would always be the same no matter rollback timings/other scenarios using the read committed isolation level. Essentially being able to declare these two atomic as long as all locks are respected by the server. I'm looking for the tiny rare differences between the two.

Comment: I'd hazard (at a guess) that the 2nd version may be more prone to Deadlocks as there are 2 stmts.... The risk would be that Lock Escalation on the Update Stmt could lock the table (or Page) while a 2nd transaction is locking from the first query. Difficult to prove though.

Comment: Thanks John, I will try to investigate further.